# Cambiar tag de html por medio de props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, props

Quisiera saber como puedo cambiar un tag de html de por ejemplo un 
`<th></th>` 
a un 
`<td></td>` 
por medio de los props del componente

Comment: Puedes pasar un elemento como propiedad y luego hacer un `cloneElement`: `React.cloneElement(this.props.tag, { children, <otras props> })` Y lo usas así: `<MyComponent tag={<td />}>...</MyComponent>`.

Answer (score 0):

La forma de cambiar de elementos en react suele hacerse a través de condiciones.
Te dejo un link interesante que habla extensamente de varias posibilidades.
https://www.robinwieruch.de/conditional-rendering-react#nested-conditional-rendering-in-react

Tambien te voy a poner un ejemplo en base a los elementos que propones en la pregunta.

Supongamos que tenemos el componente `<Tabla />` que recibe una prop, `tipoFila`.

```
<Tabla tipoFila='tr' />
```

El componente tabla tendrá dentro del método `render`, donde corresponda mostrar un tipo u otro algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
 ....
render() {
  return (
    <table>
      {this.props.tipoFila === 'tr' (
        ? <tr>....</tr>
        : <td>....</td>
      )}
    </table>
  )
}
```